# Stacked bar chart does not follow order with negative and positive values

Tags: excel, charts, stacked-bar-chart

Suppose we have a simple data that has automatically ordered from largest to smallest in excel:

| Series | value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 5 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 2 |
| b | -1 |
| e | -1.5 |

When you insert a stacked bar chart, switch rows and columns to make it stacked, the outcome is that your chart is ordered 2,3,5,-1,-1.5 from top to bottom.

If you click 'values in reverse order', you get -1.5, -1, 5,3,2.

How can I get the order to stay the same as in the table: 5,3,2,-1,-1.5 from to to bottom? Manually ordering would not work as the order is not always the same.